# How "dynamic salt" hashing works?

Tags: hash, salt

Well, I don't know what it is really called so I call it *dynamic salt* hashing. Recently, I have encountered a hashing algorithm which uses dynamic salt(generated randomly). As a result, same string produces different hash values. I wonder how it is works as well as how it is verified. The verify function takes only 2 parameters: the string and the hash value. I want to know how it works.

**Edit:**

I have seen a *similar* (but not duplicate) question to mine: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/salts-how-does-the-script-know-what-the-salt-is

Both my question and that one, is not yet answered.

Comment: It would be easier if you could tell us which algorithm it is

Comment: it is BCrypt, i think

Comment: BCrypt stores the salt inside the resulting hash value. Check out the example here, that should make it clear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt

Comment: Thanks. I have encountered that before, I've just forgot about it.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason for dynamic salt is to prevent "Rainbow table" attack.

Therefore, you will have to store the salt somewhere (e.g. in the table).
Then, each time you want to verify password you will have to get this specific salt.

The term "dynamic salt" is not that it is changing every time you verify it.
It only means that it is dynamic for each record.

[This](http://www.iaeng.org/IJCS/issues_v43/issue_1/IJCS_43_1_04.pdf) paper has everything you need to know.

Comment: As I have said, the salt is not passed as parameter when verifying.